# Boot and Login takes forever

Tags: boot, mount, login, services

My machine consists of a dual boot between Windows 10 (ssd) and Ubuntu 20.04 (hdd), 16gb ram, i7 and a GTX 1050.

Booting and loging in on Ubuntu takes forever, please check the output of systemd-analyze:

**Systemd-analyze**

```
systemd-analyze
```

```
Startup finished in 2min 28.134s (firmware) + 5.227s (loader) + 5.192s (kernel) + 1min 41.422s (userspace) = 4min 19.977s
```

**Systemd-analyze blame** (I will show the processes that takes the most)

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

```
47.117s mysql.service                                                          >
41.149s docker.service                                                         >
27.730s snapd.service                                                          >
24.662s systemd-journal-flush.service                                          >
21.383s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                     >
21.159s containerd.service                                                     >
19.829s dev-sda4.device                                                        >
16.931s tor@default.service                                                    >
14.077s postfix@-.service                                                      >
13.273s nmbd.service                                                           >
13.060s networkd-dispatcher.service                                            >
12.283s dev-loop7.device                                                       >
12.216s dev-loop17.device                                                      >
12.014s dev-loop19.device                                                      >
11.972s dev-loop20.device                                                      >
11.712s apport-autoreport.service                                              >
11.653s dev-loop27.device                                                      >
11.530s dev-loop31.device                                                      >
11.492s dev-loop25.device                                                      >
11.407s dev-loop28.device                                                      >
11.341s udisks2.service                                                        >
10.984s dev-loop22.device                                                      >
10.909s dev-loop29.device                                                      >
10.741s dev-loop21.device                                                      >
10.724s dev-loop26.device                                                      >
10.668s dev-loop12.device                                                      >
10.488s dev-loop30.device                                                      >
10.347s dev-loop24.device                                                      >
10.334s dev-loop23.device                                                      >
10.072s dev-loop14.device                                                      >
 9.968s accounts-daemon.service                                                >
 9.952s dev-loop15.device                                                      >
 9.832s dev-loop8.device                                                       >
 9.685s dev-loop10.device                                                      >
 9.642s ModemManager.service                                                   >
 8.691s dev-loop0.device                                                       >
 8.604s dev-loop16.device                                                      >
 8.432s dev-loop18.device                                                      >
 8.379s dev-loop11.device                                                      >
 8.241s dev-loop6.device                                                       >
 8.080s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                           >
 8.046s dev-loop13.device                                                      >
 7.822s dev-loop9.device                                                       >
 7.820s dev-loop3.device                                                       >
 7.805s dev-loop2.device                                                       >
 7.173s phpsessionclean.service                                                >
 7.018s grub-common.service                                                    >
 6.816s NetworkManager.service
```

**Systemd-analyze critical-chain**

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

```
graphical.target @1min 40.765s
└─multi-user.target @1min 40.765s
  └─docker.service @59.615s +41.149s
    └─network-online.target @59.614s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @38.230s +21.383s
        └─NetworkManager.service @31.413s +6.816s
          └─dbus.service @31.409s
            └─basic.target @31.209s
              └─sockets.target @31.209s
                └─snapd.socket @31.208s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @31.086s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @30.955s +130ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @29.619s +1.333s
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.955s +24.662s
                          └─systemd-journald.service @4.666s +288ms
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @4.662s
                              └─system.slice @4.658s
                                └─-.slice @4.658s
```

Please if anyone can tell me why are services like mysql and docker taking so much time, and what can I do to make the whole login time faster. Thank you

Comment: Try this, I know this shows for Ubuntu 18.04, but it also works for Ubuntu 20.04: https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/01/ubuntu-1804-lvm-swap-wait-for-root-en/

Comment: Hello. Have you tried checking the output of `dmesg` right after logging in? You should see there events whose logged time was a few seconds later than the previous one, indicating the computer took that much time performing some action. That could give you a lead as to why booting up and logging in is slow.

Comment: Do you need docker and mysql loaded during boot? Or can they be loaded later on after boot?